# Disable stored proc modify options in object explorer

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions

As business need I revoke

```
REVOKE EXECUTE ON SP_HELPTEXT TO PUBLIC;
```

it solve the purpose in query window, but how can I disable `<modify>` option present in object explorer.

`WITH ENCRYPTION` also solves the need, but not feasible in current situation. Please help me if having any other alternative.

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer

[image]

Comment: You want to Encyrpt the Store Proc

Comment: sorry don't want to encrypt the SP

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it through the GUI by right clicking on the user or the proc and going to properties. The exact steps depend on whether you are using enterprise manager or sql management studio.

Alternately add them to a role that has permissions on it already, public is the minimum required. 
exec sp_addrolemember 'public', 'user'

Comment: I did the same, but modify still enable for an user and user can see scripts. "WITH ENCRYPTION" don't want use since changing thousands of object not feasible for me and even don't have permission for the same.